# Multiple arduino boards using Johnny five are conflicting

Tags: node.js, arduino, johnny-five

I was able get both boards initialized. (thanks @ladislas).

Problem for me is that the REPL is duplicating and my controllers seem to be freaking out (spazzed servos, etc).

The boards appear to be conflicting, although they are totally different circuits so not sure what to do with the code.

Here is my code (sorry for the extra noise in it). The motor board (Arduino with motor shield) is super simple. I am just testing with the REPL. The Mega board is where most my sensors and servos are as an FYI.

```html
// Combo.js
// This program attempts to use multiple microcontrollers in the same app


// Includes
 var five = require('johnny-five');

 // Create an emitter object to receive commands from the server
 //var emitter = new eventEmitter();
 var events = require('events');
 var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();



 var boardMega = new five.Board({port: "/dev/ttyACM0"});
 var boardMotor = new five.Board({port: "/dev/ttyUSB0"});

/* var ports = [
   { id: "mega", port: "/dev/ttyACM0" },
   { id: "motor", port: "/dev/ttyUSB0" }
 ];

 var boards = new five.Boards(ports);
*/

 boardMotor.on("ready", function() {

  var configs = five.Motor.SHIELD_CONFIGS.ADAFRUIT_V1;

  var motor1 = new five.Motor(configs.M1);
  var motor2 = new five.Motor(configs.M2);
  var motor3 = new five.Motor(configs.M3);
  var motor4 = new five.Motor(configs.M4);


     // Add devices to REPL (optional)
  this.repl.inject({
   motor4: motor4 // range: 30 - 100
     });

 });


// Board Ready
 boardMega.on('ready', function(){
     // Devices 
      // Track Road Crossing
      var crossingLed1 = new five.Led(22); //crossing light 1
      var crossingLed2 = new five.Led(23); //crossing light 2
      var crossingServo = new five.Servo({
          pin: 6,
          rate: 0.05
      }); // Crossing arm
      var crossingSensor = new five.Sensor.Digital({ //crossing sensor 
          pin: 53,
          freq: 150, // how often to read the sensor in milliseconds
       });


     // Add devices to REPL (optional)
   this.repl.inject({
          crossingServo: crossingServo,
          crossingLed1: crossingLed1,
          crossingLed2: crossingLed2,
      });

      
     // Receive the command for the server
      emitter.on('command', function(command){
    
      // Check command received and execute actions
      if (command === 'crossing'){
           crossing();
           return;
      }
  
      });

     // Robot Code
      // Train Crossing
       crossingSensor.on('change', function(){
     crossing();
       });

       var crossingOn = false; // a state
       var crossingDisable; // a timeout
       var active = false;

       function crossing(){
        if(!active){
         crossingOn = true;
         crossingLed1.blink(500);
          // timer for alternating lights
          setTimeout(function(){
           crossingLed2.blink(500);
          });
          crossingServo.to(70); // lower arm
          // delay for crossing off
          crossingDisable = setTimeout(function(){
            crossingLed1.stop().off();
            crossingLed2.stop().off();
            crossingServo.to(150); // raise arm
            crossingOn = false;
          }, 3000); // milliseconds before disable
        }else{
         clearTimeout(crossingDisable);
         crossingDisable = setTimeout(function(){
            crossingLed1.stop().off();
            crossingLed2.stop().off();
            crossingServo.to(150); // raise arm
            crossingOn = false;
          }, 3000); // delay for crossing off
        }
       }


      // Next Thing..
 });

// API for use in server.js 
 module.exports = emitter;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a working example now! I started from scratch where my goal was to blink the LED on my Arduino Mega and start/stop a motor on my Arduino Uno w/ Adafruit motor shield v1.

I finally understand how to construct the multiple boards and more importantly reference them as needed. Here is my basic app. Hopefully this helps somebody else.

```
// Combo.js
// This program uses multiple microcontrollers in the same app


// Includes
    var five = require('johnny-five');

    // Create an emitter object to receive commands from the server
    var events = require('events');
    var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

    // used for debugging purposes
    var util = require('util');

    var ports = [
      { id: "mega", port: "/dev/ttyACM0" }, // this[0]
      { id: "motor", port: "/dev/ttyUSB0" } // this[1]
    ];

new five.Boards(ports).on("ready", function(){

    this.each(function(board) {

    // Initialize an Led instance on pin 13 of
    // each initialized board and strobe it.
    // new five.Led({ pin: 13, board: board }).strobe();
    });

    var led = new five.Led({
        pin: 13,
        board: this[0]
    });

    led.blink();

    var configs = five.Motor.SHIELD_CONFIGS.ADAFRUIT_V1;

    // assign board to arduino with motor shield
    configs.M4.board = this[1];

    //console.log("configs");
    //console.log(util.inspect(configs, false, null));

    var motor4 = new five.Motor(configs.M4);
        console.log("motor4 starting");
        motor4.reverse(100);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("motor4 braking");
            motor4.brake();

        }, 1000);

        // Add devices to REPL (optional)

    this.repl.inject({
        motor4: motor4  // range: 30 - 100
    });

});



// API for use in server.js 
    module.exports = emitter;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `five.Boards` class is really useful for this.

You can also use your individual board code in your original question by passing the board in by name:

```
new five.Led({ pin: 13, board: boardMega });
```

or

```
configs.M4.board = boardMotor;
```

Keep in mind that when you type `configs.M4.board = board`, you are modifying a global configuration object.  So this approach won't work if you are using two boards, both with one of those motor shields.  Instead, you'd want to deep-clone the configuration object.

```
var configs = deepClone(five.Motor.SHIELD_CONFIGS.ADAFRUIT_V1);
configs.M4.board = this[1];
```

DeepClone is an exercise left to the implementer, but there are plenty of options out there (including LoDash, or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`)